# Magento - setRelatedLinkData() only saves one link

Tags: php, magento

i'm currently working on a little extension to make it possible to adopt related products of a group product on its associated products.

It work really fine, with the exception, that only the last of the 19 related product is saves and written to the database.

I've checked my source code over and over, even with my team collegue - the code seems to be correct.

In the following i've posted the snippet with the essential parts and i hope that anyone can give me a hint or an advice to solve this problem.

Best regards
Markus

```
$supplyList =$product->getRelatedProductIds();
$associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
$params = array();
$_associatedProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

$prodCount=0;

foreach($supplyList as $sup)
{
    $params[$sup] = array('position'=>$prodCount);
    $prodCount++;
}

foreach($associatedProducts as $prod)
{
    $_associatedProduct
    ->load($prod->getId())
    ->setRelatedLinkData($params)
    ->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following an update for the problem mentioned in the first post.
Today it worked as it should, without changes made by myself or my collegue.
I'm not sure what the cause of the problem was (caches are disabled since last Monday) and the source was already correct implemented.

It works now and this post is solved, sadly without a solution.

best regards